# GUID with a always equal number

Tags: c#, guid

Why in the middle of every GUID that this computer generates, we can see a 4?

[image]

Comment: A simple google search returns: `The four bits of digit M indicate the UUID version` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier

Comment: Well it was a particular thing, i tought it was related to the machine

Comment: This is why GUID's should not be used as random numbers. OK, a version 4 GUID (which these are) consists of mostly random bits but some of the bits are fixed to comply with RFC 4122. If 128 random bits are needed just use a suitable random number generator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's `GUID` algorithm *version* (`4` in your case):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

> In its canonical textual representation, the sixteen octets of a UUID
>   are represented as 32 hexadecimal (base 16) digits, displayed in five
>   groups separated by hyphens, in the form 8-4-4-4-12 for a total of 36
>   characters (32 alphanumeric characters and four hyphens). For example:
>
> ```
> 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000
> xxxxxxxx-xxxx-Mxxx-Nxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
> ```
>
> The four bits of digit M indicate the UUID version, and the one to
>   three most significant bits of digit N indicate the UUID variant. In
>   the example, M is 1 and N is a (10xx), meaning that the UUID is a
>   variant 1, version 1 UUID; that is, a time-based DCE/RFC 4122 UUID.

Comment: I'm gonna accept this answer, i have maybe a stupid question, why are they putting the char - instead of unifying everything?

Comment: @Marco Salerno: I'm sorry, I don't follow you: UUID is *128-bit number* which can be *represented as a string* in `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-Mxxx-Nxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`. The third chunk - `Mxxx` is in fact *16-bit integer* in hexadecimal representation. The top *4 bits* - `M` are version (so we can have it in 0..15 range). I can't see any *char* here

Comment: I mean, why when it's rapresented as a string, they divide chunks with - ?

Comment: @Marco Salerno: The very 1st version of the `GUID` follows `TimeLow-TimeMid-TimeHiAndVersion-ClockSeq-Node` scheme and it was convenient to reprsent chunks separated; now we use different approaches to generate GUID, but keep on using the old representation

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the version of `GUID/UUID's` that are being used;

Some good information can be found [here](https://betterexplained.com/articles/the-quick-guide-to-guids/), but basicly these are version 4 which uses the following format:

```
 xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```